# Upgrading to react 0.67

Tags: swift, react-native

Getting error

```
Undefined symbol: swift::swift51override_conformsToSwiftProtocol(swift::TargetMetadata<swift::InProcess> const*, swift::TargetProtocolDescriptor<swift::InProcess> const*, __swift::__runtime::llvm::StringRef, swift::TargetProtocolConformanceDescriptor<swift::InProcess> const* (*)(swift::TargetMetadata<swift::InProcess> const*, swift::TargetProtocolDescriptor<swift::InProcess> const*, __swift::__runtime::llvm::StringRef))
```

Full error log
`

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/vishalkumar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/HealthCareApp-cprohhcddjbwrrbvutzfzhlmladk/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/CocoaAsyncSocket'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/vishalkumar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/HealthCareApp-cprohhcddjbwrrbvutzfzhlmladk/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Flipper'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/vishalkumar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/HealthCareApp-cprohhcddjbwrrbvutzfzhlmladk/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Flipper-DoubleConversion'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/vishalkumar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/HealthCareApp-cprohhcddjbwrrbvutzfzhlmladk/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Flipper-Folly'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/vishalkumar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/HealthCareApp-cprohhcddjbwrrbvutzfzhlmladk/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Flipper-Glog'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/vishalkumar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/HealthCareApp-cprohhcddjbwrrbvutzfzhlmladk/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Flipper-PeerTalk'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/vishalkumar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/HealthCareApp-cprohhcddjbwrrbvutzfzhlmladk/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Flipper-RSocket'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/vishalkumar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/HealthCareApp-cprohhcddjbwrrbvutzfzhlmladk/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/FlipperKit'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/vishalkumar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/HealthCareApp-cprohhcddjbwrrbvutzfzhlmladk/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Folly'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/vishalkumar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/HealthCareApp-cprohhcddjbwrrbvutzfzhlmladk/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/YogaKit'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/vishalkumar/Documents/Prudential/one-pulse-app/ios/Pods/CocoaLibEvent/lib'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/vishalkumar/Documents/Prudential/one-pulse-app/ios/Pods/OpenSSL-Universal/ios/lib'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/vishalkumar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/HealthCareApp-cprohhcddjbwrrbvutzfzhlmladk/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/React-RCTPushNotification'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F~/Documents/FacebookSDK'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Users/vishalkumar/Documents/Prudential/one-pulse-app/ios/frameworks/BabylonSDK'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Users/vishalkumar/Documents/Prudential/one-pulse-app/ios/FirebaseAnalytics'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Users/vishalkumar/Documents/Prudential/one-pulse-app/ios/FirebasePerformance'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Users/vishalkumar/Documents/Prudential/one-pulse-app/ios/ReactiveCocoa'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Users/vishalkumar/Documents/Prudential/one-pulse-app/ios/ReactiveFeedback'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Users/vishalkumar/Documents/Prudential/one-pulse-app/ios/ReactiveSwift'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Users/vishalkumar/Documents/Prudential/one-pulse-app/ios/Result'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Users/vishalkumar/Documents/Prudential/one-pulse-app/ios/SimpleKeychain'
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_swiftoverride_class_getSuperclass(swift::TargetMetadata<swift::InProcess> const*)", referenced from:
      swift::swift50override_conformsToProtocol(swift::TargetMetadata<swift::InProcess> const*, swift::TargetProtocolDescriptor<swift::InProcess> const*, swift::TargetWitnessTable<swift::InProcess> const* (*)(swift::TargetMetadata<swift::InProcess> const*, swift::TargetProtocolDescriptor<swift::InProcess> const*)) in libswiftCompatibility50.a(ProtocolConformance.cpp.o)
  "swift::swift51override_conformsToSwiftProtocol(swift::TargetMetadata<swift::InProcess> const*, swift::TargetProtocolDescriptor<swift::InProcess> const*, __swift::__runtime::llvm::StringRef, swift::TargetProtocolConformanceDescriptor<swift::InProcess> const* (*)(swift::TargetMetadata<swift::InProcess> const*, swift::TargetProtocolDescriptor<swift::InProcess> const*, __swift::__runtime::llvm::StringRef))", referenced from:
      _Swift50Overrides in libswiftCompatibility50.a(Overrides.cpp.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Undefined symbol: _swiftoverride_class_getSuperclass(swift::TargetMetadata<swift::InProcess> const*)

Undefined symbol: swift::swift51override_conformsToSwiftProtocol(swift::TargetMetadata<swift::InProcess> const*, swift::TargetProtocolDescriptor<swift::InProcess> const*, __swift::__runtime::llvm::StringRef, swift::TargetProtocolConformanceDescriptor<swift::InProcess> const* (*)(swift::TargetMetadata<swift::InProcess> const*, swift::TargetProtocolDescriptor<swift::InProcess> const*, __swift::__runtime::llvm::StringRef))


Getting error while running the application on simulator
```

Comment: Are you using M1 mac?

Comment: No, iUsing intel mac

Comment: Have you sorted out this..